# Textrures missing when I export FBX

Tags: texturing

I have a model I created with bones from Mixamo. The FBX has embeded textures.
I want to rename the bones in the model to get rid on the Mixamo in the beginning of each bone name. (this is find with Mixamo). I removed the Mixamo from the names, but then I export as FBX, the textures are gone. I am wondering how to reapply the textures to the model, or how to save the FBX with the textures.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. Download Autodesk FBX Converter (free). Run the converter. Add FBX Converter. Select Add. Now first select the FBX to be converted, then control select the Texture Directory. You have to do it in the order. Then on the right side, check Embed media. Then convert. You will have your FBX with embedded textures! Amazing how easy.

Comment: What is the end application where converted .FBX files are sent to?

Comment: I send it to Unity3D. But it probably would work in other apps.

Comment: I have one that I have done. I created it in MakeHuman. Rigged it with Mixamo.com. Then I edited it in Blender to remove the mixamo.com for each bone name. That is where it lost the connection to the textures. If you would like to have it, I can email it to you. Go to my web site and at the bottom you will see a contact message. https://jdscogin.wixsite.com/jdscogin

Comment: I didn't mean to download the file, the reason I asked was about how textures were used by end application. In cases of some render engines textures are assigned via materials which are dependant on render engines, so in those cases using this to assign textures at the very least won't really work.

Comment: Ok but it does work in Unity. For sure.

Comment: Embedded textures in FBX files do work but usually aren't worth the hassle. Mostly you will want to set up materials and control textures separately from mesh importing.